# Speed up connection to MySQL

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, mysql, performance

So here's one for you. Any idea on a way to shorten the time it takes to connect to a MySQL database?

The reason I'm wondering is because I find that just connecting to the DB adds just over a second to the rendering of the page and that seems a bit long considering Apache and MySQL is running on the same machine and the mysqli_connect is connecting to localhost. It's just such a shame when the connection takes a second while any query I end up doing won't add any significant amount of time to the render/load time.

Any ways to shorten the time it takes to open a connection?

Comment: It is not normal to have 1 second connection delay. Can you test if the same delay applies when connecting using standard mysql client? Can you connect from console and let us know if you are still facing the same delay?

Comment: Have you tried switching localhost for 127.0.0.1 ? You can also try adding skip-name-resolve to your my.cnf.

Comment: @JamesYale Just tried using 127.0.0.1 and it connected, well the page rendered, a lot faster. I'm a bit baffled by the difference...

Comment: @Hex Connecting with the mysqli client doesn't exactly give me a time to go by but it seemed to connect a bit quicker than in my quick php test page but about the same. Switching to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost did the same thing in this case, connection next to instant.

Comment: Did you check if you can see any logs regarding the delay?

Comment: Nope, nothing about it in any log. Unless there is any good reasons to not use 127.0.0.1 when connecting, seems unlikely, I'd say this is solved. If @JamesYale wants credit for the answer, considering it was due to his comment I tried 127.0.0.1 he should make an answer about it, otherwise I'll mark the one that's already there by John since it's kind of the same.

Comment: Suspect this is due to some problem resolving localhost - perhaps it's missing from the system hosts file. I don't see any reason not to use 127.0.0.1 as the target for your MySQL connection though. As for the rep, @John Gardeniers got it onto an answer before me, so may as well mark that one as the answer.

Comment: @JamesYale Checked my hosts file actually, localhost is in there. No delay for the lookup if I bring up cmd or powershell and ping localhost. Hmm, doesn't matter I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so little information to go on it's hard to offer much but I will tell you that you will be better off setting your configuration to connect to MySQL by IP (127.0.0.1) address than by name. If nothing else, you will remove one complete layer from the connection.

Comment: By specifying `127.0.0.1` the client will use a network connection, but by specifying `localhost` the client will choose a socket connection over network and thus eliminating the use of the network layer.

Comment: And yet is is faster in most cases.

Comment: It's faster to access MySQL through network rather than a unix socket? New to me.

Comment: You didn't read the question properly, which is about the initial connection, not the access time.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it's faster to open a network connection than a socket connection?

Comment: If you open a connection *as* a socket it should be faster but again, you've failed to read the question properly, or simply don't understand `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: I did not try to comment the original question at all.

Comment: This is indeed a good solution as the slow connection seem to have been due to the lookup being done for localhost. Amazing how slow that was.

@pkhamre While it's appreciated that you try to help you really should have checked the question, not only because you're commenting on an answer for a question but also because by doing so you would have seen the tags and known that it wouldn't choose a unix socket since I'm running on Windows.

Comment: Doh! I'm sorry.

Comment: Would those people downvoting this answer please take a moment to read *and understand* the question. Reading an answer without considering the context in which it is given is nothing short of stupidity.

Comment: It's clearly the right answer, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is local, you can skip networking (TCP/IP, DNS, etc) and use a socket or network-pipe connection to MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking

Answer (score -1):

You should use persistent connexion from your application to the mysql server, this way you won't have to initiate a new TCP connexion each time a request is done.

Have a look at this documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Update: Care to explain why I got that downvote ?